# Dismiss in Alertdialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, dismiss

The problem with the AlertDialog is that when I use dismiss () the AlertDialog does not appear. If I do not use dismiss () the AlertDialog appears, but then how do I disappear it if I have setCancelable in false. I call dismiss in this way:

> AlertDialog alertDialog;
>
> alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
>
> alertDialog.setTitle("Sinchronize....");
>
> alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
>
> alertDialog.setMessage("Wait");
>
> alertDialog.show();

To eliminate it use

> if (alertDialog.isShowing()) {
>                       alertDialog.dismiss();
>                   }

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are experiencing and what you are trying to get to happen.

Comment: Can u paste the full code please, where this is not working? thanks

Comment: in an activity I use an alertdialog, up to here all right, when I want to destroy it I use dismiss (), however when I use it and execute the application it does not show the alertdialog anymore

Comment: @ChristianEnciso It is working, you simply do not see it. The dialog shows up and gets dismissed. Where in the `Activity` lifecycle are you displaying it? Where are you dismissing it?

Comment: I tried a timer of 10 seconds but still does not show it.

Comment: Show where these calls are made. `onCreate`, `onResume`?

Comment: in a public void, after running an asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You can have for example "Cancel" button and execute dismiss() when this button is clicked or if you want to dismiss dialog by itself you can use Handler and execute code after some time.